# Sending multiple transactions but one would always fail

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I've created my JS and [Solidity](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/) smart contracts and both of them works fine.

But I've written them in a way where they are called together. Two of the functions are from different contracts.

Whenever i press the button to activate the functions 3 transactions (2 transactions of contract A & 1 transaction of contract B) would appear. I attached a [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t28sn.png).

If I press confirm for all, the first contract that is called will have a successful transaction but **the second one wouldn't**.

```
if (typeof(web3) === "undefined") {
   error("Unable to find web3. " + "Please run MetaMask (or something else that injects web3).");
} 
else {
   console.log("Found injected web3.");
   web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

   console.log("Connected to the Ropsten test network.");
   counterDB = web3.eth.contract(abiDB).at(addressDB);
   counterWallet = web3.eth.contract(abiWallet).at(addressWallet);                       
}
```

Is there a way where I can do everything in a single transaction? Am I writing the `web3` line correctly?

[This](http://codeshare.io/5D7KeO)  is my full source code

Comment: What you posted is not the important lines of code. You have to post the `sendTransaction` invocation. However, if you want to combine transactions, you have to do that on the contract side (ie, use a proxy contract). You can keep the transactions separate, if you want. It’ll cost a bit more in gas, though. As to why the 2nd one is failing, I’m taking a complete guess here, but the first thing I would look at is the nonce used in the second transaction and make sure it’s being incremented.

Comment: If you give full source-code I can help. As @AdamKipnis said what you wrote is not the important part.

Comment: You can look at my code here. https://codeshare.io/5D7KeO i managed to solve the problem. But now another problem arise.. When i call two functions, it will, obviously, call the two functions but the last function will be called again. Meaning 2 functions called but i'm doing transactions for 3 contracts because of the repeated call on the last function. The problems are at line 158 to 203